# Can I use the same component to render as its child in Stencil

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I have a situation where I'm using the self component to render a dynamic accordion. To do this, I'm using child component to render as a child to itself.

Example:

> <parent>
>
> ```
>     \<child\>
>
>             \<child\>\</child\>
>
>     \</child\>
> ```
>
> </parent>

When I emit an event from the inner child component, the event listener is firing twice.

Please guide me if I'm doing anything wrong here.

Or please provide me a better example to render dynamic accordions in Stencil.

Comment: Please post a complete code example so that we can see how your event listeners work.